# Convert excel formula to Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to convert excel formula to oracle sql.
**=A2&COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)**

In excel in have 2 columns: order and helper, i am running the above formula in excel column 2, which basically copy data from order column and add suffix to same order_id.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order_id</th>
      <th>Helper</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>45235</td>
      <td>452351</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>45235</td>
      <td>452352</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data in tabular form.  This is especially needed for those who know SQL, but don't know Excel.

Comment: So, what happens if there are ten or more rows with the same `order_id`? In your sample data, you have `order_id = 5407640` in three rows, and in each you add one more digit at the end (1, 2, 3). What if there are 10 such rows? Does the last row become `540764010`. adding **two** digits (1 and 0) at the end?

Comment: @mathguy In my case same order_id cannot exceed after 9 repeatations. so far i have seen its ending 3 or max at 4.. its a bad table structure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number() to acheive the same.Please find the [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=51407cc1b645c50985d39d4df24942c4)

```
    with data as(
      select 
        45235 order_id 
      from 
        dual 
      union all 
      select 
        45235 order_id 
      from 
        dual
    ) 
    select 
      order_id, 
      order_id || row_number() OVER(
        partition by order_id 
        order by 
          null
      ) 
    from 
      data order dy 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @psaraj12 for the snippet, but it will reapeat each order 4 time, while if you see in the picture i just uploaded in the question, i am counting and adding the count as suffix in column 2..

Comment: my SQL also returns the same ,have included order by,please check again

Comment: Thanks a lot @psaraj12, made few changes to your sql and got the result... got result with the below SQL select order_id, order_id || ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  order_id ORDER BY order_id) as helper from RAW_ORDER_99  where order_id = 5407640 order by 1;

Comment: "order by order_id" doesn't do anything in your analytic function (since the ordering is only within each partition, and in a given partition, "order_id" is constant). `row_number()` does indeed require an `order by` clause (for reasons that aren't clear to me); when you want to ignore that, it's better to write "order by null", to make it crystal clear that the order is irrelevant.

Comment: @mathguy updated the answer with order by as null in row_number() and it returns the same results

Comment: orderby null seems legit and efficient.